# recognize all T of all calling function1<T> at compile time then add line function2<T>()

Tags: c++, templates, macros

Is it possible to **recognize** all calling of a certain function in everywhere

```
function1<T1>(); function1<T4>(); ...
```

then add a line that calling this following line in a certain place?

```
function2<T1>(); function2<T4>(); ...
```

For example,

```
class X{
    template <class T> function1(){ }
    template <class T> function2(){ }
}

class A{}
class B{}
class C{}
int main(){
    X x;  

    //vvvv  this code (hopefully) will be auto generated (by macro?)
    x.function2<A>();
    x.function2<B>();    //<--- I don't care about order of A or B
    //x.function2<C>();  //<--- this line should not be generated
    //^^^^  Only X's function1 should be recognized,
    //             not other class's functions with the same name.

    x.function1<B>();  
    x.function1<A>();
    x.function1<B>(); ....  // called in various places in many .cpp
    //If it is called in another .cpp, but not here, it should still be recognized
}
```

### Edit

My old code call :-

```
function2<T>() inside function1<T>()
```

It costs CPU significantly (I profiled), because function1 have to check whether function2 was called or not every time.

Comment: Easy - modify `function1` to do that.

Comment: It will be slower (bad for performance).  Function2 is expensive checking.  I don't even want to cache the result because function1 is performance-critical, i.e. called really often.

Comment: `std::call_once` in `function1`?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot  Thank!  After a brief research, I doubt, is std::call_once slow?    I want near-zero cost.  Even 1 conditional checking is not allowed.

Comment: Pobably uses double-checked locking, which means one check of atomic flag. I would expect CPU branch prediction to eliminate cost of using it (as it would be always true after initial setting). Another approach will be to initialize static variable from return value of function2 (`static`s are initialized once, but it is expected to have same semantics as `call_once`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a draft of a near-zero overhead solution that will work only if you are **not** going to invoke `function1()` before `main()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <class T>
void function2()
{
    std::cout << "function2<" << typeid(T).name() << ">()" << std::endl;
}

bool dummy = true;

template <class T>
struct Func1WasInstantiated
{
    struct CallFunc2
    {
        CallFunc2() { function2<T>(); }
        void operator()() const { dummy = false; }
    };

    static CallFunc2 callFunc2;
};

template <class T>
typename Func1WasInstantiated<T>::CallFunc2 Func1WasInstantiated<T>::callFunc2;

template <class T>
void function1()
{
    Func1WasInstantiated<T>::callFunc2();
    std::cout << "function1<" << typeid(T).name() << ">()" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "------- Entered main() ---------" << std::endl;
    function1<int>();
    function1<double>();
    function1<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

Output ([check it on IDEONE](http://ideone.com/Do5xgE)):

```
function2<i>()
function2<d>()
------- Entered main() ---------
function1<i>()
function1<d>()
function1<i>()
```

The global variable `dummy` is the acceptor of the side effect, that ensures that `Func1WasInstantiated<T>::callFunc2` is linked into the program and makes the code work as intended. Without the side effect contained in `callFunc2()` I can imagine an aggressively optimizing compiler eliminating that line from `function1()` (that is normal) and letting the linker leave out the `callFunc2` objects as they become unreferenced (I cannot judge whether this would be against the C++ standard or not).